# How can I display text from a Pastebin raw file?

Tags: c#, winforms

Just trying to display a date (a expiry date) for a certain username as a label. I have a pastebin file with usernames and dates set out like this:

- username~1/1/1
- username2~2/2/2

Is there any ways to check the username and display the date for that as a label on a winform? If its best to redo the pastebin in a certain way, please let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the actual problem you have encountered? Could you clarify what you mean by "a pastebin file" (ie are you trying to write something that will download from pastebin?). I'm sure we can help you but you'll need to be more specific about what help you want!

Comment: So i'm trying to get some text off of a pastebin file & display it as a label

Comment: What do you mean by a pastebin file though? Repeating that the text is in a pastebin file doesn't make it any clearer what a pastebin file is... Pastebin is, as far as I am aware, a website that allows you to store text for easy sharing. What is there are not really files though so its kind of hard to work out what you are after. So are you talking about getting data from the pastebin website or something else?

Comment: So im hoping to use some format like this: (http://pastebin.com/ZrnagmHY) to make it so the program checks the users name then displays the date in the pastebin as a label.

Comment: Then you are asking the wrong question. What you want to know is how to get pastebin data from a website. Their API page says that you can get the raw data through this url: http://pastebin.com/raw/ZrnagmHY . You then need to find out how to get text from a webpage. I suspect there are questions on here dealing with that already - `WebClient` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) is the class you want to be looking at to help you download things.

Comment: Alright thanks Chris! Ill search around about it!

Answer (score 0):

pretty sure streamreader is able to do this.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(.RawFileHere))
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
            }
```